# Log each time $watch executed

Tags: angularjs, watch

I was wondering, is there any known way to write log every time `scope.$watch` is executed? Without putting `$log.debug` in each `$watch` method?

Maybe in a direction of interceptors/decorators?

Comment: you mean `console.log`? you would be writing the $watch function so you would just log in there ...? this question is really vague you might want to specify a little more what exactly you mean.

Comment: You're right, i've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in a controller or a run-section:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    $log.debug('digest running');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i meant a log when the $watch closure flow is being executed, not the digest running. I need to know when that if i have scope.$watch('someNewValue', function() { // i need to log that someNewValue changed } );